# Elasticsearch : get most similar result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to ElasticSearch. I need to write an api which returns most similar result match with a name.

Example: i want to find a phone has name most similar to 'samsung s6', this is my JSON query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": 'samsung s6',
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    },
    "track_scores": True
}
```

and i got (formatted on my own) :

```
6 -  Samsung S6 Edge - 5.9510574
5 - Samsung S6       - 7.512151
```

where first field is just an Id, second is Name field on which ElasticSearch performed it's searching, and third is score.

I tried to sort by *_score*:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": 'samsung s6',
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    },
    "track_scores": True,
    "sort": [
    {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

it seems work fine. But when i try with another name, i.e: 'iphone 6':

```
3 - Apple iPhone 6         - 5.569293
1 - Apple iPhone 6 Plus    - 5.8405986
```

How can i get most similar result match with name?

UPDATE:

This is mapping:

```
"device_group": {
"properties": {
"id": {
  "type": "long"
},
"name": {
  "type": "string",
}
}
}
```

Comment: elasticsearch by default sort results on the basis of score for full text queries so you don't need to do that explicitly. 
Also, Can you share your mapping body for this type of document to understand better your problem and get you a relevant answer.

Comment: I recommend to use the explain parameter at the end of the searc url. i.e.: http://yourserver/phones/device_group/_search?explain=true .  this parameters makes elasticsearch to add the explanation of the given scores along with the result. Propbably this could give you a hint.